# pass css function as jquery.css() value parameter

Tags: jquery, css

I have a css grid where I want to set the column count at runtime so I tried

```
$(".container").css('grid-template-columns', repeat(count, 1fr));
```

but I only get 1 column

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: you need to add quotes `'` for the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass in the CSS function as a string. Assuming `count` is a Javascript variable, this is probably what you're trying to do:

```
$(".container").css('grid-template-columns', 'repeat(' + count + ', 1fr)');
```

Comment: @JoeB The answer above is just missing a `#` or a `.` to `$("container")`... Pasted from your question, by the way! That makes another quite basic issue to your one line code. I suggest you read a bit more tutorials...